# Hash and Salt string in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, hash, windows-store-apps, salt, sha

I have been trying to do a Hash and salt on a password that I have to save on the device. This is a code that I have been using, but I can't find System.Security.Cryptography and the RNGCryptoServiceProvider in the Windows Store Framework.

```
public static string CreateSalt(int size)
{
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var buff = new byte[size];
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}

public static string GenerateSHA256Hash(string input, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
    SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Does anyone have an advise on how to do this on a Windows Store App?
Thanks

Comment: Why is the windows store app hashing passwords? That's not the job of a client application

Comment: I need to save a password locally and I would prefer not to save it in a plain string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative to using RNGCryptoServiceProvider

```
var buffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(saltlength);
var string = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer)
```

Windows.Security.Cryptography is the alternative to System.Security.Cryptography for windows store apps.